# Parallelising a 'for' loop in Cython: beyond prange

Tags: multithreading, multiprocessing, cython, python-multiprocessing

I am struggling to correctly parallelise a function using Cython. Basically, the problem is to bin some data. The actual code is a bit long, but in the end it does something like this:

```
def bin_var(double[:] dist,
            double[:] values,
            double[:] bin_def,
            double[:] varg, long[:] count):

    dbin = (bin_def[1] - bin_def[0]) / bin_def[2]

    for n1 in range(values.size):
            if (dist[n1] < bin_def[0]) or (dist[n1] >= bin_def[1]):
                continue
            else:
                ni = int((dist - bin_def[0]) / dbin)
                count[ni] += 1
                varg[ni] += calc_something(values[ni])

    # Compute the mean
    for n1 in range(int(bin_def[2])):
        varg[ni] /= count[ni]
```

This code lends itself to some simple parallelisation (`values` and `dist` are very large): one needs to split the first `for` loop over separate processes, each working on its own version of the `count` and `varg` arrays. When that is done, one has to combine everything together by summing the different versions of `count` and `varg` before the second *for* loop (much shorter).

That said, it's two days I'm trying to understand how to implement efficiently this in Cython, and I am starting to suspect it is not possible with the current version of the language. Note that just using `prange` from `cython.parallel` for the first loop does not provide correct results, because (I assume) of the simultaneous access of `ni`, `count` and `varg` from different threads.

Is Cython parallel support really so limited? I was getting such a nice speedup single-threaded, I just hoped I could continue...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can think of three options here:

1. Use the GIL to ensure that the `+=` is done single threaded:

   ```
   varg_ni = calc_something(values[ni]) # keep this out 
                  # of the single threaded block...
   with gil:
       count[ni] += 1
       varg[ni] += varg_ni
   ```

   This is easy and won't be too bad provided the work done in `calc_something` is reasonably large
2. Make `count` and `varg` 2D arrays with each thread writing to a different column. Sum along the second dimension afterwards:

   ```
   # rough, untested outline....

   # might need to go in a `with parallel()` block
   num_threads = openmp.omp_get_num_threads()

   cdef double[:,:] count_tmp = np.zeros((count.shape[0],num_threads))
   cdef double[:,:] varg_tmp = np.zeros((varg.shape[0],num_threads))

   # then in the loop:
   count_tmp[ni,cython.parallel.threadid()] += 1
   varg_tmp[ni,cython.parallel.threadid()] += calc_something(values[ni])

   # after the loop:
   count[:] = np.sum(count_tmp,axis=1)
   varg[:] = np.sum(varg_tmp,axis=1)
   ```

   You could also do something similar using the ideas in the [`local_buf` example in the documentation](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/parallelism.html#cython.parallel.parallel).
3. (**NOTE** - GCC is currently giving me an "internal compiler error" for this - I feel it should work, but for the moment it doesn't seem to be working, so try option 3 at your own risk...) Use the [openmp `atomic` directive](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/524509) to do the addition atomically. This requires a bit of work to circumvent Cython but shouldn't be too difficult. Create a short C header file with an `add_inplace` macro:

   ```
   #define add_inplace(x,y) _Pragma("omp atomic") x+=y
   ```

   The `_Pragma` is a C99 feature that should allow you to put pragmas in preprocessor statements. Then tell Cython about that header file (as if it's a function):

   ```
   cdef extern from "header.h":
       void add_inplace(...) nogil # just use varargs to make Cython think it accepts anything
   ```

   Then in the loop do:

   ```
   add_inplace(count[ni], 1)
   add_inplace(varg[ni], calc_something(values[ni]))
   ```

   Because this uses macro trickery it may be a bit fragile (i.e. definitely won't work with `PyObject*`s, but it should generate the correct C code when using standard C numeric types. (Inspect the code to be sure)

Comment: Thanks, I had tried the `with gil` way, but it was so slow for my `calc_something` that I did not even mention it. The other options seem on the other hand very promising.

Comment: Solution 2 was the way to go for me, but it is worth the effort only for large problems (as those I am actually interested in). Note however that `prange` has some weird behaviour, as forcing a `return` after the loop. I did not try solution 3, as it's a bit beyond reach for me.

Comment: I couldn't quite get solution 3 to work so I think you're well-advised to avoid it :)

Answer (score 1):

For everybody who is still struggling,
here is the solution that is **much faster than with gil:** .
Nowadays (7 years later), it is possible to import atomic/openmp directly.
It took me a while to figure that out since there is nothing about in the official documentation.

## The atomic solution

```
from libcpp.atomic cimport atomic
from cython.parallel cimport prange

cpdef parallel_loop():
    cdef: 
        Py_ssize_t a = 100000 
        Py_ssize_t loopvar 
        atomic[int] *atticounter1= new atomic[int](0)
        int finalvar = 0
    try:
        for loopvar in prange(a,nogil=True):
            if loopvar % 1000 == 0:
                atticounter1.fetch_add(1)
        finalvar = atticounter1.load()
    finally:
        del atticounter1
    return finalvar

f=parallel_loop()
print(f)
```

## The openmp solution

Most of the time, you want to do more than count positive results.
In this case you can use openmp.

Here is a working example of a code that locates RGB colors in an image

**The pyx file:**

```
from cython.parallel cimport prange
cimport openmp
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
import cython
cimport cython

cpdef void searchforcolor(
    unsigned char[:] pic,
    unsigned char[::1] colors,
    Py_ssize_t[:,::1] results,
    Py_ssize_t[::1] countervar,
    Py_ssize_t width,
    Py_ssize_t totallengthpic,
    Py_ssize_t totallengthcolor,
    int cpus,
    ):
    cdef:
        Py_ssize_t i, j
        unsigned char r,g,b
        openmp.omp_lock_t locker
    if cpus < 1:
        cpus=openmp.omp_get_max_threads()
    if cpus > 1:
        openmp.omp_set_num_threads(cpus)
        openmp.omp_init_lock(&locker)
        for i in prange(0, totallengthcolor, 3, nogil=True): # should be possible, but not work not working: use_threads_if=cpus>1
            r = colors[i]
            g = colors[i + 1]
            b = colors[i + 2]
            for j in range(0, totallengthpic, 3):
                if (r == pic[j]) and (g == pic[j+1]) and (b == pic[j+2]):
                    openmp.omp_set_lock(&locker)
                    results[countervar[0]][1] = ((j / 3) // width) #x
                    results[countervar[0]][0] = ((j / 3) % width) #y
                    results[countervar[0]][2] = b
                    results[countervar[0]][3] = g
                    results[countervar[0]][4] = r
                    countervar[0]+=1
                    openmp.omp_unset_lock(&locker)
        openmp.omp_destroy_lock(&locker)
    else:
        for i in range(0, totallengthcolor, 3):
            r = colors[i]
            g = colors[i + 1]
            b = colors[i + 2]
            for j in range(0, totallengthpic, 3):
                if (r == pic[j]) and (g == pic[j+1]) and (b == pic[j+2]):
                    results[countervar[0]][1] = ((j / 3) // width) #x
                    results[countervar[0]][0] = ((j / 3) % width) #y
                    countervar[0]+=1
```

**The python code:**

```
def search_colors(pic, colors, cpus=-1):
    if not isinstance(colors, np.ndarray):
        colors = np.array(colors, dtype=np.uint8)
    rav_colors = np.ascontiguousarray(colors.ravel())
    totallengthcolor = rav_colors.shape[0] - 1
    totallenghtpic = np.prod(pic.shape) - 1
    width = pic.shape[1]
    results = np.zeros((totallenghtpic, 5), dtype=np.int64)
    countervar = np.zeros(1, dtype=np.int64) # this is going to be our atomic counter
    searchforcolor(
        pic.ravel(),
        rav_colors,
        results,
        countervar,
        width,
        totallenghtpic,
        totallengthcolor,
        cpus,
    )
    return results[: countervar[0]]


picpath = r"C:\Users\hansc\Downloads\pexels-alex-andrews-2295744.jpg"
pic = cv2.imread(picpath)
colors0 = np.array([[255, 255, 255]], dtype=np.uint8)
resus0 = search_colors(pic=pic, colors=colors0)
colors1 = np.array(
    [
        (66, 71, 69),
        (62, 67, 65),
        (144, 155, 153),
        (52, 57, 55),
        (127, 138, 136),
        (53, 58, 56),
        (51, 56, 54),
        (32, 27, 18),
        (24, 17, 8),
    ],
    dtype=np.uint8,
)
resus1 = search_colors(pic=pic, colors=colors1)
print(resus1)
```

**Important: Compile both examples it with the OpenMP flag!**

Comment: Yes - that's a good suggestion. It would probably have been possible when I wrote my answer. You don't seem to delete your heap-allocated atomic though so it probably leaks memory. Also the C standard library also defines atomic operations, so those are an option if you don't want to use C++

Comment: Thank you very much for that correction! I guess that it wasn't possible, back then, but I am sure that it will help other people, because all answers that I found on stackoverflow suggest the with gil stuff.  I am still confused when I need to free something and when not in cython.  I am going to edit the answer later, and show also how to call a function

Comment: Thanks for your answer! In the meanwhile, building python bindings from C++ or other languages has become much more straightforward, and I tend to think that only the poor state of Python packaging for compiled extensions can still justify, in some situations, the use of cython.